# Pycharm - Code Cells - Using breakpoint

Tags: debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

I am using the new feature of PyCharm 2018 called 'Code cells'.
Can I place a breakpoint within the cell and have the execution break when I hit that line? I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the code cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to debug editor code cells independently, I created a feature request in PyCharm bug tracker: [PY-29672](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29672). Please feel free to vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the upcoming PyCharm 2019, it seems to support code cells debugging: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2019/02/pycharm-2019-1-eap-5/:

> Another new feature is debugging of Jupyter cells: you can [place a breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2019.1/running-ipython-notebook-cells.html), and step through what is happening to explore your analysis in detail.

Comment: I wonder whether this is about Jupyter notebooks or actual Code Cells, which is a slightly different feature. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: Using  Jupyter Notebook within pyCharm is slow and experiemental.

I would like individual cell debugging feature while in scientific mode.

Ipython backend provide all the necessary API for this.

Spyder already implemented this feature I want.
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9361